# assigning value to bool inside while loop

Tags: c#

I know this is a very newbie C# question but I am implementing a small program which does the following:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
    bool isRun = false;
                int number = 0;
                while (isRun = (true) && number < 3)
                {
                    ++number;
                    Console.WriteLine("Number = {0}", number.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine(isRun.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
}
}
}
```

At the end of the while loop, I would have expected the `bool` value to be true, but is is printed to be `false`. Why is that? Is this different from C++ where I would have done something like and the same thing in C# is giving me false

```
while(number<3)
{
is = true;
}
if(is){
cout<<true;
}
```

Comment: wow the supplemental code changes the question....

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it's generally bad practice to cause side effects in conditional expressions like this.  Mutating effects should be inside the loop, and the conditional should be side effect free.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're seeing this behavior is due to the operator precedence involved.  Here the `&&` binds more strongly than `=` so the code in the loop is actually bound as the following

```
while (isRun = (true && number < 3)) {
  ...
}
```

Once `number > 3` the `&&` expression is `false` and is assigned into the `isRun` value and simultaneously terminates the loop.  Hence once the loop exits you will see `isRun` as `false`

To get the behavior you are looking for you will need to manually correct the precedence with parens.

```
while ((isRun = (true)) && number < 3) {
  ...
}
```

Note: In general, as @Servey pointed out, the assignment of locals to expressions inside the loop predicate is considered bad practice.  Many C# users would actually be surprised that code compiles at all because they've been conditioned to only use `==` in loops.

It's more idiomatic to simply set `isRun` to `true` on the first line of the loop for this pattern.

```
while (number < 3) {
  isRun = true;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you have set you `boolean` variable to `false` and without assigning it back to `true`, in while loop you are `matching` it against the `value true`, thus it `fails` in `every` case.

Comment: He's assigning it to true, not comparing it to true.  It's `=` not `==`.